# Lisp: How to override default string representation for CLOS class?

Tags: string, lisp, common-lisp, representation, clos

In Common Lisp, how can I override the default string representation of a CLOS class so that calls to `format` or `princ` will print something intelligible, even when objects of that class are embedded within other types, such as lists or arrays?

For example, if I call `(format t "~a~%" x)` when x holds an instance of my solution class, I want it to print something like `#<SOLUTION genes: #(1 2 3) scores: #(4 5) rank: 6>` instead of `#<SOLUTION {BB7CD31}>`.

So far, all I have managed to figure out is writing custom functions to handle printing structures that I know will contain instances of this class, but this is tedious.  Surely Lisp provides some way to get this functionality for free?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check out [`print-object`](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/stagenfun_print-object.html).

Comment: This was what I needed.  As a stylistic question, what is the "best" way to print to the passed stream inside this method?  I am currently using `format`, but it seems strange to call the function that may very well be calling this method.

Comment: `format` won't call your method recursively by itself - that's something you'd have to do. Also, many, many CL projects have examples of `print-object` methods. Browse through them to see how other projects typically define them.

Answer (score 18):

You should be looking at `print-object` and `print-unreadable-object`. Suppose you have a class named `FOO` like so:

```
(defclass foo ()
  ((name :accessor foo-name)))
```

And you want to print instances like this: `#<FOO "xyz">` where `"xyz"` is the content of slot `name`. In this case, the following implementation of `print-object` would do what you want:

```
(defmethod print-object ((obj foo) out)
  (print-unreadable-object (obj out :type t)
    (format out "~s" (foo-name obj))))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you also look [22.1.3.13 Printing Other Objects](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/22_acm.htm)  it suggests [print-unreadable-object](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/m_pr_unr.htm#print-unreadable-object) as a common format macro for such situations